# Why doesn't kernel inherit filesystem info from GRUB?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, boot

I've read that GRUB understands filesystem and can access the kernel by looking at /boot, so it loads the kernel which in turn loads some drivers to mount the file system with the aid of initrd.

So, my question is: why kernel needs to mount the filesystem while GRUB knows it why doesn't it inherit directly from GRUB or something?
Maybe the question is really about the concept of mounting what it really means, is it some mapping between file hierarchy and disk addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the bootloader (Grub) and the operating system (Linux) have a [driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) for the filesystem, i.e. a piece of code that understands commands such as “read data from a file”. The operating system can't use the driver from the bootloader because once the bootloader has loaded the operating system in memory, the bootloader is erased from memory. (And also because the bootloader's driver is typically less capable than the OS's — for example Grub's filesystem drivers can only read, not write.)

Mounting a filesystem at a path `/some/where` means that accesses to files under `/some/where` are routed to that filesystem. When the kernel executes a command on a file name (open, delete, rename, etc.), it analyzes the path to the file, determines which filesystem the file is on based on the list of currently mounted filesystems, and dispatches the request to the appropriate driver. Mounting is internal to the operating system, it doesn't affect the hardware in any way, so there's no way for mounting state to be transferred from the bootloader to the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB's task is to load the kernel (and initrd), pass some arguments to the kernel and start it. To be able to do that, it knows about disk partitions and can read filesystems. Mounting a file system involves filling in data structures in the kernel, to enable the kernel to keep track of the structure of the file hierarchy. GRUB is not part of the kernel, and it doesn't really know anything about this hierarchy. It is told to look for stuff in a filesystem on a given partition, but it doesn't know it is going to be called `/boot` or where it will be mounted by the kernel. (Ok, it may pass parameters to the kernel saying so, but that's not really "knowing".)

GRUB's task is to "do one thing, and do it well". GRUB is also not the only bootloader capable of starting the Linux kernel, and is not even available on most architectures, so the kernel can't depend on it.

Comment: And on the other hand Grub boots a lot more than just Linux.

Comment: So, how GRUB knows the location of the kernel if it doesn't know the hierarchy. I don't believe it uses raw sectors as I read it does not.
My idea about accessing filesystem is following the hierarchial tree starting from the root down to the wanted files, how would I do that without knowing the hierarchy structure.

Comment: I understand the last line that kernel cannot depend on the bootloader, it may be something other than GRUB, LILO for instance, which doesn't know about filesystems. So this means that kernel duplicates the work of GRUB right?

Comment: What I meant was that GRUB does not know where the filesystems will be mounted when the system is up and running. GRUB does know the hierarchy within the filesystem. Yes, there is duplicate code, but I would say it's GRUB that duplicates the code of the kernel.